# How do I apply CSS to the table generated into another window?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am unsure where to apply my CSS to the table I have generated. I am getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/content/08/10674308/html/venuesearch.php on line 133

My line 133 is this

```
$resultString .= "<div id=".table-2" class=\\\"results\\\">There are " .  $result->num_rows . " results for $city, $state:<br /><br /><table>";
```

Here is the code I am working with

```
<?php

    include "dbc.php"; 

    $query = <<<EOF
SELECT * FROM
    venueprofile 
WHERE 
    city= '$city' 
    AND 
    st= '$state'
    AND
    capacity 
    BETWEEN 
        $capacity1 
        AND 
        $capacity2; 
EOF;

if ($result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)){
    $resultString = "<html>";
    $resultString .= "<head><link href=\\\"default.css\\\" rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\"       `enter code here`type=\\\"text/css\\\" media=\\\"all\\\" /></head><body>";  

    $resultString .= "<div id=".table-2" class=\\\"results\\\">There are " . $result-`enter code here`>num_rows . " results for $city, $state:<br /><br /><table>";

    $resultString .= "  <tr><thead><th></th>";
    $resultString .= "      <th>Venue Name</th>";
    $resultString .= "      <th>Capacity</th>";
    $resultString .= "      <th>City</th>";
    $resultString .= "      <th>State</th>";
    $resultString .= "      <th>Telephone</th>";
    $resultString .= "      <th>Contact</th>";
    $resultString .= "      <th>Email</th>";    
    $resultString .= "  </thead></tr>";
    $rowCount = 0;
    while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rowCount++;
        $resultString .= "<tbody><tr>";
        $resultString .= "<td>$rowCount</td>";
        $resultString .= "<td>" . $row['VenueName'] . "</td>";
        $resultString .= "<td>" . $row['capacity'] . "</td>";
        $resultString .= "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
        $resultString .= "<td>" . $row['st'] . "</td>";
        $resultString .= "<td>" . $row['tele'] . "</td>";
        $resultString .= "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
        $resultString .= "<td>" . $row['EmailAddress'] . "</td>";       
        $resultString .= "</tr></tbody>";
    }
    $resultString .= "</table></div></body></html>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    newWindow("resultsWindow"+(resultsWindows.length - 1),"<?php echo $resultString; ?`enter code here`>",400,400);
</script>
<?php
```

External CSS

```css
#table-2 {
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
        width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
}
#table-2 td, #table-2 th {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #333;
}


#table-2 thead {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    padding: .2em 0 .2em .5em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #4B4B4B;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2f2f2), to(#e3e3e3), color-stop(.6,#B3B3B3));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D6D6D6, #B0B0B0, #B3B3B3 90%);
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
}
#table-2 th {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: white 1px 1px 1px;
}
#table-2 td {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
#table-2 td:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Is the path of the CSS properly identified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line has indeed an error, change this:

```
$resultString .= "<div id=".table-2" class=\\\"results\\\">There are " .  $result->num_rows . " results for $city, $state:<br /><br /><table>";
```

to this:

```
$resultString .= "<div id='table-2' class='results'>There are " .  $result->num_rows . " results for $city, $state:<br /><br /><table>";
```

The problem was with the way you concatenated `table-2`, because you used the `.` concatenation operator, and then didn't use it to concatenate it with the rest of the string. Also, you just wanted to concatenate `table-2` as a stringe (as this is the `id` defined in your CSS) and not as a variable (which would be `$table-2` anyways).

So that caused a bunch of mistakes.

Also, not sure why you did all that escaping, while you needed just one <kbd>backslash</kbd> or just using the single quotes inside your double quotes.

Comment: Oops now I get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /home/content/08/10674308/html/venuesearch.php on line 133 Help!

Comment: Indeed there was a syntax error in my answer. I edited it and it should be alright now.

Comment: Seems to work. Now I just have to tune the look of the report and I have it. Thanks so much for your help. I feel pretty dumb at this stuff. Everyday, I learn 10 new things. Now off to my city to city google waypoints issue. It is a tough one so far.